# Recommendations About A Testing Software/Tool For a C# Project That Uses DevExpress And Web Services

Tags: c#, framework, software-testing, web-services

I am looking for some software or tool for testing a C# project with the following features

- Uses DevExpress framework
- It is a desktop Application that works only with an Internet connection designed only for Windows (7 or above Windows OS) and the application checks if there are new updates automatically.
- The application connects to two different web services: one ws is used for user control and the other for calling a series of stored procedures which the application works for DB operations
- Also the web services are developed in C# language

Mainly I am focused on testing the application, but if you have any suggestions about tools for Web Service testing, your recommendation is also welcome.

Comment: "`suggestions about tools for Web Service testing`" - Selenium - every time

Comment: Any other suggestion or it's the only one you know? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's the industry standard fo9r testing browser based apps. Maybe you just want to test your REST API? If so, the industry standard for that is [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/)

Comment: Awesome, I will learn more about the two options recommended, can you post your answer as a new comment to check you as the correct answer? Thank you :)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution that suited you?

Answer (score 1):

The industry standard for automating & testing web apps (browser pages) is [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/).

If you want to test your REST API, the industry standard for that is [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/)

Both are free.